# Extracting area codes using extract() on R

Tags: r

```
calls <- calls %>% extract(col = caller_id_number, into = "area_code", regex = "([\\012-]+)", remove = F)
view(calls)
```

Using the extract function on R, I want to extract the area code of a phone number. For example: 394-000-0000, I would want to extract out the 394. The problem is, I don't know how to set the regex up in the extract() function to recognize the pattern of an area code. Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: if it is always the first 3 digits why not use the simpler `str_sub` from the `stringr` library?

Comment: @D.J the first three digits may not be the first characters... codermcgee - do some of your phone numbers have, e.g., parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex `[0-9]` matches all digits from 0 to 9, and we can give exact quantities in curly braces. So the pattern `[0-9]{3}` will match exactly three digits. `stringr::str_extract()` will give you the first match by default. So this should work:

```
library(stringr)
calls %>% 
  mutate(area_code = str_extract(caller_id_number, "[0-9]{3}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
calls$area_code <- sub(".*([0-9]{3}).*", "\\1", calls$caller_id_number)
```